# PrincipalContext constructor and AD querying

Tags: c#, active-directory

Can someone explain to me slightly more detailed, why the following code works:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"some.domain.com", "username","password"))
```

But when I try to pass anything else to the constructor, such as an IP address and port, I get errors?

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"123.45.56.78:910", "username","password"))
```

The above line doesn't work, but I want to be able to access the AD from a computer outside of it, if it has valid credentials, how would I do that, and why does one example work, while the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You are close, you are are just missing `LDAP://` at the beginning of your IP address.

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"LDAP://123.45.56.78:910", "username","password"))
```

LDAP is a protocol that allows you to communicate with your Active Directory domain.

Comment: This does not work, even if I try it from my PC (which is in the AD); I get a PrincipalServerDown exception.

Comment: @Elnherjar What protocol are you using to communicate with your AD domain?